Solving the system with $x_i+y_j=a_{ij}$, for $i,j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and $\sum_{i = 1}^nx_i - \sum_{j = 1}^ny_j = \lambda$
Something I'm doing in my research boils down to this problem:

Let $n$ be even (not sure if this matters, but only the even $n$ matter for what I'm doing). Suppose we have $2n$ variables, $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n, y_1, y_2, ..., y_n$, and a system of equations
$$x_i + y_j = a_{ij}$$ for each $i, j \in \{1, 2, ..., n\}$, and then one final equation
$$\sum_{i = 1}^nx_i - \sum_{j = 1}^ny_j = \lambda$$ Does there exist a solution? (The $a_{ij}$ and $\lambda$ are constants, but fixed).

For $n = 2$ we were able to find a solution, but the general case is evading me. It is overdetermined, so if there's no way to solve this I suppose I'll have to go back and see if there's some symmetries in what led to this system that I missed.

What is the underlying problem that lead you to this system? Might be useful to add that.

I'm not sure if that will be helpful, it involves the groupoid C*-algebra for a non-Hausdorff groupoid and certain limits. I guess the main thing I should have put in my original post is that the solution will tell me what $a_{ij}$ will work, which will let me describe a certain subalgebra.
Through some tedious row reduction last night I was able to see that it is at least solvable (with certain conditions on the $a_{ij}$, but I couldn't see a nice way to descibe it. I'm going to look through Ryszard Szwarc's answer below tonight though

You might want to try this: Consider the minimization problem
$$
\min z=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n
x_i-\sum_{j=1}^ny_j-\lambda\right)^2\
\text{s.t.}\quad x_i+y_j=a_{ij},\ i,j\in{1,\cdots,n}.
$$
The original system of equations have a solution iff $z^*=0$.

Assume that $i$ varies from $1$ to $n$ while $j$ from $1$ to $m.$ The space of all matrices $n\times m$ has dimension $mn.$ Consider matrices of the form $$a_{ij}=x_i+y_j\quad (*)$$ for some $x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\ y\in \mathbb{R}^m.$ The representation is not unique as $$a_{ij}=(x_i+t)+(y_j-t)\quad (**)$$ It is not hard to prove that two representations of the form $(*)$ are related by $(**).$ Therefore the dimension of the space of matrices satisfying $(*)$ has dimension $n+m-1.$ Clearly, $n+m-1<nm $ except the trivial case $n=m=1.$ Therefore not every matrix is of the form $(*).$
For example, when $n=2$ and $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij},$ i.e. $\{a_{ij}\}_{i,j=1}^2$ is the identity matrix, then
$$x_1+y_1=x_2+y_2=1,\quad x_1+y_2=x_2+y_1=0$$ Thus $$ 2=x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2=0$$ which leads to a contradiction.
Given $\{a_{ij}\}$ satisfying $(*)$ we get
$$\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i+t)-\sum_{j=1}^n (y_j-t)=\left (\sum_{i=1}^m x_i-\sum_{j=1}^n y_j\right )+(n+m)t$$
Therefore for given $\lambda$ we may find $t$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^m(x_i+t)-\sum_{j=1}^n (y_j-t)+(n+m)t=\lambda$$
Namely
$$ t={1\over n+m}\lambda -{1\over n+m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m x_i-\sum_{j=1}^n y_j\right )$$

Thank you, I will take a look through this tonight and let you know if I have any questions

This looks good, and the requirements you found are exactly what I expected to see! So that's great. If you don't mind me asking, how did you figure this out? Did you just play around with it?

The answer can be simplified substantially. I am re-editing.
